# If I reduce ADC sample rate, do I get an average over the time period?

Tags: esp32, adc, signal-processing

I am working with a ESP32-C3 devkit. I am using the internal ADC on that chip to read from an analog microphone. I initialize the ADC like this:

```
adc_continuous_config_t dig_cfg = {
    .sample_freq_hz = 20000,
    // ...
};
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(adc_continuous_config(handle, &dig_cfg));
```

If I reduce the sample frequency to, say 1000 Hz, then will each sample represent, roughly, an average of 20 samples from my previous stream (where the sample frequency was 20,000 Hz)? Or is it more like I will get just one out of every 20 samples from the original stream?

The reason I ask is that I'm hoping to perform a kind of low-pass filter by changing the ADC sampling frequency and I'm wondering what's going on inside the ADC hardware when I change the sampling frequency.

Comment: This really depends on the hardware inside the processor.  Some chip makers like NXP have configurable ADC circuits where the hardware can average several samples for every reported value.  Others may not.  You really have to dive into the processor's specifications / configuration.  Also investigate the number of significant bits.  Just because an ADC has 8 bits does not necessarily mean it has 8 bits of resolution.

Comment: Most people would rather do the filtering in the digital domain: you have so much flexibility for the filter design…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly not. The ADC on the Arduino Uno (a different processor, I know) uses the "sample and hold" technique. This means that the ADC samples the input voltage at a point in time, copying it into a sample-and-hold capacitor. It then successively compares it to be above or below threshold voltages to generate the individual bits of the resulting number. I have some details about the Uno ADC [here](http://gammon.com.au/adc).

It probably does this so that, when sampling a rapidly changing signal (like audio) it samples a moment in time, rather than having the comparison be of a signal that is changing over time.

I can't find technical details for the ESP32 ADC sampling method, but it seems likely that a lower sample rate will simply sample less data points, not take an average. This  could lead to wildly inaccurate results.

You might want to check out the [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) to see the reasons for choosing a certain sample rate.

If you want an average, feeding the signal into a suitably-sized RC filter might be a good way of finding an average voltage.